# From fancyimpute import KNN - how to install packages

Tags: python, libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fancyimpute import KNN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import chi2_contigency
import seaborn as sns
from random import randrange, uniform
```

I was trying to run this command and but error occured no module found fancyimpute. Then I tried to install fancy impute by using `pip install` but

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   tensorflow (from fancyimpute) (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching
>   distribution found for tensorflow (from fancyimpute) occured for
>   scipy.stats and random as well
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   scipy.stats (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution
>   found for scipy.stats

I just want to know how will I be able to install these packages?

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the dependencies manually:

first install `tensorflow`:

you could just run:
    pip install tensorflow

or follow these instructions:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

then you have install `scipy`:

```
pip install scipy
```

or follow these instructions:
https://scipy.org/install.html

If there are still problem, please specify your python Version, downloaded dependencies and your system-environment.